# CSS3 Sprite Images not showing

Tags: css, css-sprites

I created a template for an HTML website and for the footer I am using CSS3 Sprite images so that I use classes to call one image rather than using multiple images. Here is the template on this URL - http://testingnew1.comule.com/ . The CSS3 Sprite is in the footer above the links on the website.
The CSS3 sprite should appear like the link below.

http://mywebprojects.net16.net/

Could someone help me please, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Kind Regards,
Ronny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it says that the file is not found.

Try to rename the image file name to one without `-`

i.e rename it from `hostinger-600x400-2.gif` to `hostinger600x4002.gif` and deploy it after changing references in header and footer

Comment: I have no use of - in the image file. It is in the images folder.

Comment: This is the piece of code it is not picking up " background:url(images/brands.png) no-repeat center; "

Comment: try background:url('images/brands.png')

Comment: Is there anything else you can suggest.

Comment: where have you used image sprite in the test site?

Comment: Used in the footer section above the Computer fixes and information header and the mouse image. The gap you see in the footer is where the sprite should be appearing

Comment: its a path error
try url(../../images/brands.png) no-repeat center
it worked for me

Comment: Is was working fine after coming back from lunch. For some reason I was ../ for the beginning of the path URL but there was no change. But It is working fine. Thank you.